# Highchart plotLines z Index between series z Index

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to create a fiddle, mocking up the image attached [image]

in following jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/2TuCW/162/

The problem is I want the plotLines between blue line and green column. 
 I tried changing the zIndexes of plotLines (10) , between blue line (15) and green column (5) in following fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/2TuCW/163/

```
//plotLines zIndex
"plotLines" : [
        {
            "color": '#E5E7EB',
            "zIndex": 10,
            "width":    2,
            "value": 20 

        },

....
....
//Series data z-index 
    "series": [{
        "type":"column",
        "data": [35,39,49,50,57,58],
        "zIndex":5 
        ....
        ....
    "series": [{
        "type":"line",
        "data": [35,39,49,50,57,58],
        "zIndex":15
```

But it is not working as expected. Please suggest how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

It is related with fact that all series have the same zIndex.

Related topic: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3321

Answer (score 0):

Try to adjust the values of the plotLines.

If you want a plot line to be between blue line and green column the value of the plotLines has to be between the data of blue line and data of column.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems that plotLines can either be in front of *all* series or behind *all* series. This is because all series are grouped under a common element. A plotLine element is a sibling to the group element, not a sibling to the individual series elements.

Answer (score 0):

This issue relates to the fact that all series are drawn within the same group, and therefore have the same z-index related to other groups. [A related GitHub issue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/3321) has discussion and code examples.

See [this one example solution](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/r3Lzjjz6/1/), proposed by Torstein Hønsi (Highcharts creator). I've made a modified, [minimal, reproducible example here](https://jsfiddle.net/rhs3w172/):

```
/**
 * Plugin to allow plot band Z indexes in between series
 */
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.PlotLineOrBand.prototype, 'render', function (proceed) {
    var chart = this.axis.chart;

    proceed.call(this);

    if (!chart.seriesGroup) {
        chart.seriesGroup = chart.renderer.g('series-group')
            .attr({ zIndex: 3 })
            .add();
    }

    if (this.svgElem.parentGroup !== chart.seriesGroup) {
        this.svgElem
            .attr({ zIndex: this.options.zIndex })
            .add(chart.seriesGroup);
    }
    return this;
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        plotLines: [{
            color: 'red',
            width: 2,
            value: 3.5,
            zIndex: 10
        }]
    },
    series: [{
        data: [7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227],
        zIndex: 9
    }, {
        data: [8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111],
        zIndex: 11
    }]
});
```

The code uses Torsteins plugin to allow the plotline in between series. See the GitHub issues for discussion on caveats and potential improvements.